# AI Image Generator Using MNIST Only Generates 1 Image

Tags: python, pytorch, mnist

I'm making an AI-Image Generator using Torch and MNIST. I have one script for training the model, and another for generating the image based on a prompt (100 values from -1 to 1 separated by commas). I started to notice that the image was always the same no matter the prompt... And when I modified the code to show me what images it was generating while training, every image was the same - the image that came up in the prompts as well. Here is my script for training the model:

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
from torchvision import transforms, datasets, utils
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import os

# Define the generator model architecture
class Generator(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Generator, self).__init__()
        self.model = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Linear(100, 256),
            nn.LeakyReLU(0.2),
            nn.Linear(256, 512),
            nn.LeakyReLU(0.2),
            nn.Linear(512, 1024),
            nn.LeakyReLU(0.2),
            nn.Linear(1024, 784),
            nn.Tanh()
        )

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.model(x)
        x = x.view(x.size(0), 1, 28, 28)  # Reshape the output to match image dimensions
        return x


# Set device
device = torch.device("cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")

# Load and preprocess the dataset
transform = transforms.Compose([
    transforms.ToTensor(),
    # Add more transformations if needed
])

# Replace 'path_to_dataset' with the path to your dataset
dataset = datasets.MNIST(root='path_to_dataset', train=True, transform=transform, download=True)
data_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(dataset, batch_size=64, shuffle=True)

# Initialize the generator model
generator = Generator().to(device)

# Initialize a new optimizer
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(generator.parameters(), lr=0.0002, betas=(0.5, 0.999))

# Check if a saved checkpoint exists
checkpoint_file = 'generator_model_epoch10.pth'
if os.path.exists(checkpoint_file):
    if torch.cuda.is_available():
        checkpoint = torch.load(checkpoint_file)
    else:
        checkpoint = torch.load(checkpoint_file, map_location=torch.device('cpu'))
    
    # Load the generator model and optimizer state
    generator.load_state_dict(checkpoint['generator_state_dict'])
    optimizer.load_state_dict(checkpoint['optimizer_state_dict'])
    epoch = checkpoint['epoch']
else:
    epoch = 0

# Continue training
num_epochs = 10

# Create a directory to save the generated images
os.makedirs("generated_images", exist_ok=True)

for epoch in range(epoch + 1, epoch + num_epochs + 1):
    for batch_idx, (real_images, _) in enumerate(data_loader):
        # Move real images to device
        real_images = real_images.to(device)

        # Generate random noise
        noise = torch.randn(real_images.size(0), 100).to(device)

        # Generate fake images
        fake_images = generator(noise)

        # Train the generator
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        loss = nn.MSELoss()(fake_images, real_images)
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()

        # Print training progress
        if batch_idx % 100 == 0:
            print(f"Epoch [{epoch}/{epoch + num_epochs}], Batch [{batch_idx}/{len(data_loader) - 1}], Loss: {loss.item()}")

        # Save and display generated images
        if batch_idx % 500 == 0:
            # Save generated images
            utils.save_image(fake_images[:25], f"generated_images/epoch_{epoch}_batch_{batch_idx}.png", nrow=5, normalize=True)
            
            # Display generated images
            fig, axes = plt.subplots(5, 5, figsize=(10, 10))
            for i, ax in enumerate(axes.flatten()):
                ax.imshow(fake_images[i].cpu().detach().squeeze(), cmap='gray')
                ax.axis('off')
            plt.show()

    # Save the model and optimizer state at the end of each epoch
    torch.save({
        'epoch': epoch,
        'generator_state_dict': generator.state_dict(),
        'optimizer_state_dict': optimizer.state_dict(),
    }, checkpoint_file)
```

And here is the code for my image generator(Using the trained model in the above script)

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
from torchvision.utils import save_image

# Define the generator model architecture
class Generator(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Generator, self).__init__()
        self.model = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Linear(100, 256),
            nn.LeakyReLU(0.2),
            nn.Linear(256, 512),
            nn.LeakyReLU(0.2),
            nn.Linear(512, 1024),
            nn.LeakyReLU(0.2),
            nn.Linear(1024, 784),
            nn.Tanh()
        )

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.model(x)
        x = x.view(x.size(0), 1, 28, 28)  # Reshape the output to match image dimensions
        return x

# Set device
device = torch.device("cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")

# Initialize the generator model
generator = Generator().to(device)

# Load the trained generator model
checkpoint_file = 'generator_model_epoch10.pth'
checkpoint = torch.load(checkpoint_file, map_location=device)
generator.load_state_dict(checkpoint['generator_state_dict'])

# Set the generator in evaluation mode
generator.eval()

# Prompt the user to input a prompt vector
prompt_input = input("Enter a prompt vector (100 comma-separated values): ")
prompt_values = [float(x.strip()) for x in prompt_input.split(",")]
prompt = torch.tensor(prompt_values, dtype=torch.float).reshape(1, 100).to(device)

# Generate an image based on the prompt
with torch.no_grad():
    generated_image = generator(prompt)

# Save the generated image
save_image(generated_image, 'generated_image.png')
```

Thanks for any help. I'm not sure what would make the model only produce the same image even during training, and I don't think it is to do with the data set because I'm using MNIST.
Thanks in advance for any help.

**EDIT:**
It turns out that the images were not identical - after using an online tool, it turns out that there are tiny differences in the pixels. I suppose this means that the model is learning, however why they are so identical I don't know.